# Visualizing region unions

Tags: graphics, regions, visualization

I usually look at my regions by plugging them into graphics:

```
Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]}]
```

That works. But when I try to create the union of the regions, I can no longer visualize it (this fails):

```
Graphics[RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]]]
```

Why? And how can I visualize a region constructed through unions?

Incidentally, [the documentation for RegionMember](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html) suggests that `Region[RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]]]` should generate an image. But it doesn't for me.

Comment: What version are you using? `Region` was introduced in V11.1.

Comment: @ChipHurst Ahh, I see. I'm using V11.0, naturally. There's a good reason to update!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amplifying on the answer by [`e.doroskevic`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18696/e-doroskevic)

The Head of [`RegionUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html) is `RegionUnion` which is not a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) primitive.

```
Head@RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]]

(*  RegionUnion  *)

RegionQ@RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]]

(*  True  *)
```

Use [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)

```
RegionPlot[
 RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]], AspectRatio -> 4/7]
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `AspectRatio -> All` instead.

Comment: @CarlWoll - Thanks.

Comment: @CarlWoll `AspectRatio -> All` produces an error in 10.1.  Did you mean `AspectRatio -> Automatic` or is this something new?  If the latter how is it different from `Automatic`?

Comment: `All` was just the first I thing I tried, and in M11 I think `All` and `Automatic` are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion):

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    RegionUnion[{Disk[{0,0},2],Disk[{3,0},2]}]
]
```

[image]

If you want a better discretization, you can use [`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal)/[`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal):

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    RegionUnion[{Disk[{0,0},2],Disk[{3,0},2]}],
    PrecisionGoal->6
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Input

```
RegionPlot @ RegionUnion[{Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]}]
```

### Output

[image: region plot output]

Answer (score 4):

In V11.1.1 a new function [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html) was introduced, which among other usages, makes viewing compound regions dirt simple.

```
Region @ RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]]
```

[image: region]